# Spaces in newenvironment

Tags: spacing, environments

I observed an unwanted behavior of my self-made environment. The following code sometimes creates spaces after the environment head and sometimes doesn't.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newenvironment{Theorem}[1][]{%
    \medskip%
    \par%
    \noindent%
    \textbf{Theorem.}%
    \ifthenelse{ \equal{#1}{} }{}{ (#1)}%
    \it%
    }%
    {%
    \smallskip\par%
    }

\newenvironment{Theorem2}{%
    \medskip%
    \par%
    \noindent%
    \textbf{Theorem.}%
    \it%
    }%
    {%
    \smallskip\par%
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{Theorem}
That is a cool Theorem
\end{Theorem}

\begin{Theorem}[of some famous guy]
    That is a cool Theorem
\end{Theorem}

\begin{Theorem2}
another cool theorem
\end{Theorem2}

\begin{Theorem2}%
another cool theorem
\end{Theorem2}

\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image: Code result]

Is there a way of forcing LaTeX to ignore all normal spaces in the definition of an environment such that I can only add spaces by `\space`?

And can I add something to the definition of the environment such that it ignores all spaces and pars that appear directly after the call of the environment such that

```
\begin{Theorem2}
some text
\end{Theorem2}
```

produces the same as

```
\begin{Theorem2}%
some text
\end{Theorem2}
```

?

Comment: What's wrong with `\usepackage{amsthm}` and `\newtheorem*{Theorem}{Theorem}`?

Comment: the space is not space in your definition it is space added (or not) _in the document_

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes! Use `\ignorespaces` at the end of the first argument to `\newenvironment`

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{Theorem2}{%
    \medskip%
    \par%
    \noindent%
    \textbf{Theorem.}%
    \itshape\ignorespaces%
    }%
    {%
    \smallskip\par%
    }
\begin{document}
  \begin{Theorem2}
  some text
  \end{Theorem2}
\end{document}
```

`\ignorespaces` is a primitive that ignores the next spaces until some text is to be output. When you do e.g. `\newenvironment{thm}{}{}` then a macro `\thm` is made, which in turn is the last macro executed by the `\begin{thm}` command.

Comment: okay thanks I will try that. But is there also a way to ignore all normal space signs in the definition of an environment?

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek not that I know of.

Comment: hmm anyway your command seems enough to make the environment do what it was supposed to do.

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek No, *Inside* a definition, you just have to write a space where you want one, and *not* write a space where you don't want one! (That's why lines in definitions often end with `%`, of course)

Comment: `\ignorespaces` is a good tool, but in your particular case the problem is you *don't* have a space in the definition after the `\textbf` or `\it`. If you include a space there, another space when *using* the environment doesn't matter, because  multiple spaces are equivalent to a single space. So just deleting the `%` at the end of the `\textbf` line will fix the problem.

Comment: @alephzero I think the OP did _not_ want the space?

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman The OP says the unwanted behaviour is that it sometimes creates spaces and sometimes doesn't. I assumed that in normal English text, you *always* want a space in the output after 'Theorem.'

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman I want controll over the spaces.

Comment: @alephzero somehow i get two spaces or at least a bigger space between theorem and the text if i do what you have suggested

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek Oops, my bad. `\textbf{…}` <space> `\it` <space> will create two spaces in the output.

Comment: Btw: Please remove `\it` which is quite deprecated and use the LaTeX syntax.

Comment: @TeXnician used `\textsl` instead. Approved?

Comment: I guess that it's not the same, most fonts do not even provide slanted. Why not `\itshape`?

Comment: @TeXnician That's the one!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is: use `xparse` and exploit that in the scope of `\ExplSyntaxOn` spaces are ignored; one can use `~` to insert a real space.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{Theorem}{o}
 {
  \par\addvspace{\medskipamount}
  \noindent
  \normalfont
  \textbf{Theorem.~}
  \IfValueT{#1}{(#1)~}
  \itshape\ignorespaces
 }
 {
  \par\addvspace{\smallskipamount}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Some text before the theorem to see the vertical spacing
in context.

\begin{Theorem}
That is a cool Theorem
\end{Theorem}

Some text after and before the theorem to see the vertical spacing
in context.

\begin{Theorem}[of some famous guy]
    That is a cool Theorem
\end{Theorem}

Some text after the theorem to see the vertical spacing
in context.

\end{document}
```

I made some adjustments: `\medskip` and `\smallskip` are wrong in this context. However, `\smallskipamount` is definitely too small as the image shows. With `\addvspace` the vertical spaces don't accumulate; with your code two consecutive theorems would be separated by a small skip plus a medium skip.

[image]

On the other hand, `\newtheorem*` from `amsthm` is much simpler.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem*{Theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

Some text before the theorem to see the vertical spacing
in context.

\begin{Theorem}
That is a cool Theorem
\end{Theorem}

Some text after and before the theorem to see the vertical spacing
in context.

\begin{Theorem}[of some famous guy]
    That is a cool Theorem
\end{Theorem}

Some text after the theorem to see the vertical spacing
in context.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So if you do at the beginning and at the end `\medskip` and one theorem follows an other then between them is still one `\medskip` instead of two?

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek With `\addvspace` only one, with `\medskip` two.

Comment: In normal TeX, `~` is a little different from a normal space, in that it prevents a line break (possibly among other effects—I can't remember).  Is it so also in `\ExplSyntaxOn`?

Comment: @LSpice In the scope of `\ExplSyntaxOn` the character `~` denotes a space. No strings attached. If, in that framework, you want a nonbreaking space, use `\nobreakspace`.

Comment: @egreg, thanks!  "No strings attached" is a very apt way of saying that it's no longer a tie. 